# Qlikview - join columnin expressions

Tags: qlikview

I have Two column:

```
Col1               Col2
A                   D
B                   E
C                   F
```

I want in expression to join columns and get

```
     Col
      A
      B
      C
      D
      E
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T1:
LOAD * INLINE [
Col1
A
B
C
];

T2:
LOAD * INLINE [
Col2
D
E
F
];

T:
Load 
    Col1 as Col
Resident T1;

Load 
    Col2 as Col
Resident T2;

drop tables T1,T2;

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain that, but I'll assume that Col1 and Col2 are part of the same table, like this :

```
BASETABLE:
LOAD * INLINE [
    Col1,Col2
    A,D
    B,E    
    C,F
];
```

You can then, using the fact that Qlikview assumes that the same column name is the same data to do this :

```
NEWTABLE:
LOAD Col1 as Col Resident BASETABLE;
LOAD Col2 as Col Resident BASETABLE;
```

The NEWTABLE will have a single column with data from Col1 and Col2.

Comment: No, Col1 table1 and col2 table 2, and table don't have the same number of column...

Comment: Same principle applies still. On the example I gave initially both LOAD...RESIDENT commands point to the same table (BASETABLE), you just need to point them to the right column names / table names.